# how to pass password after a long run of a process

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hi all I am learning python script and I am stuck now ,(using wxpython for GUI)

My issue is , i wants to run build.system but that build.system is asking for system password after its execution starts, I have tried using pexpect and i cant use "sudo". because of some reason I cant use sudo I have tried this also

```
subprocess.call("echo ******* | sudo -S ./build.system %s" % (str(mode)))
```

using Pexpect:

```
child = pexpect.spawn("./build.system %s" % (str(mode)))
child.interact()
child.expect("[sudo] password for system:")
child.sendline("********")
```

I have tried linux command expect also.
output i got:

```
INFO: building for board
INFO: keeping existing sandbox /home/system/sandbox
[sudo] password for system:
```

expected is:

```
INFO: building for Stretch board
INFO: keeping existing sandbox /home/qvisdvr/sandbox
[sudo] password for qvisdvr:********install alarms/alarms.h
install alarms/alarms_int.h
install ccm/ccm.h
install common/defines.h
[contd]
```

Looking for good suggestion, Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are there errors? How does this fail? What do you see - what did you expect?

Comment: @JonClements: no errors , but i cant pass password to terminal, i mean when process starts to execute . First make clean then ./build.system

Comment: @nammu You may need to escape some characters in the password. For example, "pa$$" would needed to be replaced by "pa\$\$" to be correctly interpreted.

Comment: @Salem:I am not able to pass password, i have edited question .

Comment: @JonClements: i have edited the my question please look over it once

Comment: @nammu If I run a similar code of yours I get an error in `subprocess`. If you get any error you really should post them! Also what do you mean with "no able to pass password"? The system hangs (ie expecting for the password)? You get a error because sudo has failed (incorrect password attempts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      try:
          proc = subprocess.Popen(["./build.system  %s "  % (str(mode))], shell=True)
          proc.stdin.write("******")
          proc.stdin.flush()
      except AttributeError:
          pass
```

This worked for me.